# Connecting TeamCity 8.1.3 to VS online Git

Tags: git, tfs, teamcity, azure-devops

I'm trying to connect TeamCity to a Git instance on Visual Studio Online. I've followed all the correct processes and added alternative credentials. These credentials work as I have TeamCity connecting to a TFSC instance on Visual Studio online.

I can connect to the repository and push to it from GitExtensions so I know the repository is fine. I'm struggling to work out what I've done wrong.

My error is:

> **TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server:**
>
> https://myAccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/TestTFSGit.
>
> Team Foundation Server Url: https://myAccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/TestTFSGit.
>
> **Possible reasons for failure include:**
>
> - The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
> - The Team Foundation Server is offline.
> - The password has expired or is incorrect.
>
> **Technical information (for administrator):**
>
> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

The URL exists and resolves to my Visual Studio Online Git project.  I have the following settings in the VCS root settings on TeamCity. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do not configure it as Team Foundation Server, but instead configure it as Git.

Comment: Just tried that and it worked - could you post that as an answer and I'll tick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Team City means "Team Foundation Version Control" or TFVC when you select "Team Foundation Server". When connecting to a TFS hosted Git repository, you can select Git as Type of VCS instead.